# Closure Compiler insists a value can be null when it cannot be

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have a structure which is typed as follows:

```
 /** @type {!Array<{
   *  cmd: string,
   *  params: !Array<{name: string}>,
   *  do: function(!Object, !Array<!Roll20Object>, !Array<string>, boolean):string
   * }>} */
```

One of the values loaded into the structure includes the following field:

```
   do: ((p,t,r,a) => {
      /** @type {!Array<string|number|boolean>} */
      let results = _.map(t, x => getTokenAttr(x,p.property));
```

GetTokenAttr's return type is `{null|string|number}`. `_.map` is typed as follows in the externs for underscore.js:

```
/**
 * Object-style annotation
 * @param {Object|Array} obj
 * @param {Function} iterator
 * @param {Object=} opt_context
 * @return {!Array|_}
 */
```

Closure gives the following error compiling the structure:

```
pf2utils.js:1029: WARNING - [JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH] initializing variable
found   : (Array|_|null)
required: Array<(boolean|number|string)>
                let results = _.map(t, x => getTokenAttr(x,p.property));
```

It seems to be claiming that `results` has the possibility of being `null`, but it is not clear where this is coming from. The `do` declaration promises that the `t` parameter is not null (as it's `!Array<..>` and the extern for `_.map` promises it does not return null (because of `@return {!Array|_}`). But Closure is treating `_.map`s return as `(Array|_|null}` instead, unprompted.

How can I tell Closure that this is a valid assignment and should be null free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `_` is declared as a class (with @constructor), it is nullable by default, the type `_` is equivalent to `!_|null`.  The return type for map should be, if it can not return null, would be `!Array|!_` not `!Array|_`.

You can verify the different in the Closure compiler "debugger" playground with this [snippet](https://closure-compiler-debugger.appspot.com/#input0%3D%252F**%2520%2540constructor%2520*%252F%250Afunction%2520_()%2520%257B%257D%250A%250A%252F**%2520%2540type%2520%257B!Array%257C_%257D%2520*%252F%250Alet%2520x%2520%253D%2520null%253B%250A%250A%252F**%2520%2540type%2520%257B!Array%257C!_%257D%2520*%252F%250Alet%2520y%2520%253D%2520null%253B%26input1%26conformanceConfig%26externs%26refasterjs-template%26includeDefaultExterns%3Dtrue%26CHECK_TYPES%3Dtrue%26REWRITE_MODULES_BEFORE_TYPECHECKING%3Dtrue%26CLOSURE_PASS%3Dtrue%26PRESERVE_TYPE_ANNOTATIONS%3Dtrue%26PRETTY_PRINT%3Dtrue), where the assignment to `x` is allowed but the assignment to `y` is rejected:

```js
/** @constructor */
function _() {}

/** @type {!Array|_} */
let x = null;  // valid

/** @type {!Array|!_} */
let y = null;  // type error
```

Comment: Thanks. It just looks like the underscore.js externs are really out of date..